# Bad Image Exception while loading SQLite DLL

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll, runtime-error

I have a project that is build on Any CPU configuration, `.Net Framework 2.0`, vs2008 with 32bit version of `SQLite` dll used in it. 
Well this works fine on my 32 processor environment, but when i ran this project on 64bit processor environment i experienced

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture-neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies.
```

An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

I even tried adding 64 bit dll on my project but it did not work.

I have tried all the solutions but that did not work for me. Since i am bound to build the project on 32 bit machine, i need a way to run this tool on my 64 bit environment too.

Any suggestions/comments/improvements means a lot for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try and build it using x86 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your application using x86 configuration.

When dealing with dlls like SQLLite that are compiled for x86, your process must be running in x86 mode.

Comment: You are right but there might be a way i could make it work in a 64 bit environment. Because it is possible but i am having only this dll issues, rest 32 bit projects runs successfully in my 64 bit environment.

Comment: Rest of the dlls are .NET dlls?

Answer (score 0):

I find these steps can be used to deal with sqlite.

1. Download [NuGet](http://nuget.org/nuget.exe)
2. open `cmd` and type `nuget install System.Data.Sqlite` -- note it will create a folder in your current directory
3. copy dlls from *net20* folders to your solution like so.
   [image]
4. Add a reference to System.Data.SQLite.dll
5. Make sure you copy both SQLite.Interop.dlls to your output dir
   [image: Copy to output Folder]

Hope it helps.